# Javascript boolean array operations

Tags: javascript

I have an instrestion question about boolean logiс in javascript.

I have a FOR circle and created a trigger event, which will store TRUE or FALSE for IF statement:

```
var trigger = [];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

    //Checking for empty fields
    if(this.form.rows[i].fields[0].input.val() === '') {
        if($(this.form.rows[i].row[0]).length){

        bla bla bla

        trigger.push(true)
        }

        else {

        trigger.push(false);
        }
    }
```

So in the end I want to check each statement of array for boolean operator AND

```
if(trigger & ??? )
```

Any help friends ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: Do you want to *count* how often `true` is in the array or test whether *all* entries are `true`? What else are you doing with `trigger`? Do you need an array at all? `&` is *bitwise* AND btw.

Comment: Man, i want to check by boolean logic if the statement will be correct ('111' & '111') will return TRUE

Comment: Still not clear and `'111' & '111'` actually returns `111`. I honestly suggest you to take some more time to phrase your question properly. It is not easy to understand what you want to do (or maybe it's just me who does not understand it).

Comment: boolean operator and is `&&` .. if you want to check if 2 variables have the same value you can use `==` or `===` for both value and type (strict comparison) checks

Comment: Ok, how i can check each statement in array if it's TRUE, than return true ?

Comment: Friends, look at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)), that what i mean - get result mask - if it's '111' than return true, else false

Comment: Masks are numbers though, not arrays. Why don't you just increase a counter instead of adding `true` to the array and later test whether `$counter === 3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on one of your comments

> Ok, how i can check each statement in array if it's TRUE, than return
>   true

Like this, for example:

```
var alltrue = !/false/i.test(trigger.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks man -i've used your solution, but i think it'll be buggy in different browsers

Answer (score 1):

*(I've marked new lines of code with `//@@@`)*
I assume you want to check if each statement is true. Then, there are two ways, depending on if the "bla bla bla" is actually there.

If the forloop is only for checking if every field is empty (i.e. the "bla bla" is empty), and the trigger array isn't being used afterwards, your if statement can be compactly written as:

```
var trigger = [];
var empty=false; //@@@
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

    //Checking for empty fields
    if(this.form.rows[i].fields[0].input.val() === '') {
        if($(this.form.rows[i].row[0]).length){
        }

        else {
        empty=true; //@@@
        break; //@@@
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to use trigger afterwards, do this:

```
var trigger = [];
var dummy=[];  //@@@@
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

    //Checking for empty fields
    if(this.form.rows[i].fields[0].input.val() === '') {
        if($(this.form.rows[i].row[0]).length){

        bla bla bla

        trigger.push(true)
        }

        else {

        trigger.push(false);
        }

        dummy.push(true);   //@@@@
    }

//Use this if block:
if(dummy.toString()=trigger.toString()){
   //Insert stuff here
}
//Alternatively,  use this:

if(dummy && trigger){
   //Insert stuff here
}
```